# How to show related products Magento 2.3.5

Tags: product, product-attribute, products, product-collection, related-products

I want to show related products on product page only from my custom module.
I am not sure if I can or is it possible to do it.
I am doing a check by if my attribute is enable I will change the outcome of Is saleable function.
I want to show related products on my phtml can anyone show me how to do this or tip

Answer (score 1):

> Try this hope it will help you.

```
 $_quickShopHelper =  $this->helper('Emthemes\QuickShop\Helper\Data');
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

    case 'related-rule':
        if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getAllItems();
            $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
            $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showWishlist = true;
            $showCompare = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;

    case 'related':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
        if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
            $type = 'related';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'related_products_list';
            $title = __('Related Products');
            $items = $block->getItems();
            $limit = 0;
            $shuffle = 0;
            $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

            $showWishlist = true;
            $showCompare = true;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $description = false;
        }
    break;
```

?>

> html part this is lengthy but you can modify as per your need

```
<?php if ($exist):?>

    <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
        <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
            <div class="block <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class; ?>" data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}' data-limit="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $limit; ?>" data-shuffle="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $shuffle; ?>">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="block <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class; ?>" data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}' data-limit="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $limit; ?>" data-shuffle="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $shuffle; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="block-title title">
        <strong id="block-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class?>-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ if($title=="Related Products") { echo "Similar Products"; } else { echo $title; } ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $class?>-heading">
        <?php if ($type == 'relateda' && $canItemsAddToCart): ?>
        <div class="block-actions">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>
            <button type="button" class="action select" role="select-all"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('select all') ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $type; ?>">       
            <ul class="products list items product-items owl-carousel">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                <?php $available = ''; ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($type == 'related'): ?>
                        <li class="item product product-item" style="display: none;">
                <?php else: ?>
                        <li class="item product product-item">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product-item-info <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $available; ?>">
                    <div class="product-shop-top">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="em-element-display-hover bottom">
                        <div class="em-btn-addto">
                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                   <!-- <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?>">
                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?></span>
                                                    </button>-->
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                    ?>
                                                    <!-- <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?>">
                                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Buy Now') ?></span>
                                                    </button> -->
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare): ?>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showWishlist): ?>
                                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item); ?>'  class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>                                          
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_quickShopHelper->getConfig('quickshop/general/active')): ?>
                            <?php echo $_quickShopHelper->getQuickShopButton($_item); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                        </strong>

                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_item); ?>

                            <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'relateda'): ?>
                                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                    <div class="field choice related">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related" id="related-checkbox<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                                        <label class="label" for="related-checkbox<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span></label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: What will be the html part for this I am struggling on that now I can’t get it to show, I have put this case but I can’t put the html, as in how to load the title image and price for related products

Comment: Okey I will help for html part

Comment: Thank you @jykmhar

Comment: Try this reference

Comment: I will give this a try

Comment: I tried to put this in and I get error, the phtml part you send me I believe it doesn’t have a closing if statement but I am not sure if that’s right either

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple. You can even achieve this just by overwriting the template.

Just copy the content of `magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml` in to your theme `YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` and then change the logic for this `$block->getItems()`:

```
case 'related':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
    if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) { //change the logic
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getItems(); //change logic
        $limit = 0;
        $shuffle = 0;
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
    break;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh what will be the html part to show it in frontend, would I just move whatever is in the item.phtml to my module. I don’t want to move it into theme I want a separate module that’s why

Comment: Yes, you should copy the entire content of that file and change the logic as you want. You may have noticed that file is used for other types too.